# Replace words in a sentence without unnecessary spaces?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the sentence: "*I am a beautiful turtle*" and I would like to be able to replace arbitrary words from such a sentence. The problem is that I do not want unnecessary spaces. Thus, `sentence.replace(/ *\w+ */g, "")` won't work since it would add a space in front or after the sentence and `sentence.replace(/\w+g, "")` wouldn't work either.

Comment: _"I would like to be able to replace arbitrary words from such a sentence"_ why don't you just do something like `sentence.replace(/beautiful/g, "wonderful")`? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: To remove words without leaving unnecessary spaces.

Comment: Another approach is to use `.split(" ")`, change the array, then use `.join(" ")`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove specific words and get rid of the extra spaces, do this:

```js
const removeWord = (s, w) =>
  s.replace(new RegExp(`^${w}\\s+|\\s+${w}\\b|$\\b{w}\\s+|\\b${w}\b`, 'g'), '');

const str = 'this is a beautiful turtle.';

console.log(removeWord(str, 'this'));
console.log(removeWord(str, 'is'));
console.log(removeWord(str, 'a'));
console.log(removeWord(str, 'beautiful'));
console.log(removeWord(str, 'turtle'));
```

The regex `\s+beautiful` will match the word `beautiful` including any number of spaces before the word.

Comment: However, if you were to remove "turtle" you'd be left with an unnecessary space before the end

Comment: @VLAZ, I will fix this

Comment: You can just add `.trim()` after replace, nut this will replace `AbeautifulA` also you need to consider word boundaries too

Comment: or `/\s*turtle(?!\s*)/g` would also fix it I tthink

Comment: Does not work. If try to replace "this" or "turtle", it leaves an unnecessary space before or after the sentence :/

Comment: @step just use `.replace(/\s*beautiful\s*/g, ' ').trim()` if will get rid of space at start and end

Comment: The problem with trim is that it might remove spaces that were already there

Comment: @CodeManiac until you get a sentence with a fullstop - `"this is a beautiful turtle."` replacing "turtle", leaving a space, and trimming ends up with `"this is a beautiful ."` The same problem exists with other punctuation, too `"this is a beautiful turtle, bro"` -> `"this is a beautiful , bro"`

Comment: The problem is the definition of "unnecessary spaces". You need a specific understanding of the language involved, where spaces are ok, and where spaces should be removed. Also, to take the last example, what about removing `bro` -> `"this is a beautiful turtle,"`: Should there be a space after the comma or not?